# How do you calculate the effective mass of holes given both light and heavy holes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I'm trying to calculate the effective density of states for valence bands in a semiconductor. It has given me the effective masses of two types of holes (light and heavy). How do I use these two effective masses to solve this equation?

I'm assuming I should combine the effective masses, but I'm not sure how.

[image]

Comment: Consider the two separately and add them.

Comment: @JonCuster add the density of states? why?

Comment: You are just counting the number of states.  There are so many in the light hole band, and so many in the heavy hole band.  The total is the sum.

Comment: @garyp but Nv is the density, not the total number of states. I am not sure what the units are exactly, but I'm not seeing how you would simply add them

Comment: The density of states does not depend on temperature, but it does depend on energy (missing in your expression).  I think what you have there is the number of "occupied" holes at temperature $T$.